# I want to get a log file of exactly the things my Powershell script does?

Tags: powershell, logging

I've been trying to get the steps that the script does into a txt file, but I just can't get my head around it

```
$days = -2
$date = (get-date).adddays($days)
$lastboot = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$Computer = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=TEST-OU,OU=EDV,DC=Kolbe-Druck,DC=de' -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name

$lastbootconverted = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime($lastboot)

write-host $date

write-host $lastboot

write-host $lastbootconverted

if($date -gt $lastbootconverted)
{
    write-host Need to reboot
    (Stop-Computer $Computer -Force)
}
else
{
    write-host no need to reboot
}
```

any tips?

Comment: Start-Transcript ? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your text into a txt with this code:

```
"Test" | Out-File -FilePath "Your Path to the txtfile" -Append
```

I would make a function, so you dont have to write this line more than once

EDIT:
You can also add a timestamp:

```
"Test " + $(Get-Date -Format g) | out-file....
```

Comment: I already tried Out-File, but it didnt work... Where do I need to put it? I just started with scripting a few days ago, so I don't really know how to make a function.

Comment: That depends on what you want to have in that file. For example you might want to do `$lastboot| | Out-File -FilePath "Your Path to the txtfile" -Append` You will have to do this for each variable you want to write to file seperately.

Comment: Instead of write- host you will write my line which I posted and instead of test at the beginning you write text you want in the logfile. As example your last line: `"no need to reboot | $Date " | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Logfile.txt" -Append`